# How to connect firebase analytics with a react-native EXPO APP?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-analytics, analytics

I have a reac-native APP, which I am trying to connect to firebase analytics, to get statistics about which screens the APP user is viewing the most and how long it stays on each screen. I've searched the firebase documentation on the internet, github, even found a lot about it but I still can't send these statistics to firebase analytics (which screen the user views most and how long it stays on each screen).

Could you give me a tutorial, a very detailed walkthrough, how to send these statistics to firebase, please?

As I am doing in react-native, javascript, the APP is later compiled for Android and iOS. I already downloaded the google-services.json file, but it doesn't send all the events I want.

I'm using Expo SDK: 35.0.0, react-native: 0.59.8, expo-cli: 3.11.1

Comment: There are tutorials on the firebase console to connect your app to firebase, you can download a plist file -ios and a json file - android, once you you have properly set up the library go back on the console to see if the app is registered with firebase. Then you can create a conversation on firebase. Once you have created a conversation you can use firebase.logevent (look on the docs on how to do this) when the event has been logged the conversation will show up in events. you can add custom parameters to the event, be sure to mark it as a conversation under the events tab. Good luck!